# HTTP network traffic and randomness

Tags: javascript, http-headers, network-traffic, client-side-scripting

I am doing studies on HTTP and how it works. I used the console of Google Chrome to see the network traffic going to the Web server. I have check different websites. It seems that sometimes in some generated requests there are some random values passing to the Web server. For example a particular request has a parameter which its value is timestamps. I have also noticed that there are parameters which take different values each time!!

I have always used Google Chrome. If the browser changes these different values make sense. I may say that different browser may behave differently and may generate different values after executing a particular JavaScript function. But, in my case, the browser always is the same but I see different values for a particular parameter in one specific HTTP request.

- What id the purpose of having random values in HTTP requests?
- Why there is timestamps in some HTTP requests?
- Is that also possible to have some random responses come from Server side?
- Is there any security concern behind this behavior?

I could not find any article or any other resource which explain why randomness is important or even is used in HTTP traffics.

- Is there any article I can refer to?

Comment: If ypu see ?rnd=1236913766312 - it is likely someone tries to keep the request out of cache. Also jQuery JSONP will create random callback functionnames

Comment: Then, they are not used to keep track of the client, right? like cookies? Do you know any resource to suggest me so that I can read for getting more info on this?